# C#/Linq: Grouping not working as expected

Tags: c#, database, linq

I am refreshing by Linq skills, and have hit a snag - the second grouping isn't doing what I think it should. The grouping of pair by pair.Key does not seem to group at all, just collate. It reorders the artists so all the ones with the same genre appear sequentially, but does not group them.

```
// Create a list of pairs of GenreName and ArtistName
var genres_and_artist =
    from artist in db.Artists
    join track in db.Tracks on artist.ArtistId equals track.ArtistId
    join genre in db.Genres on track.GenreId equals genre.GenreId
    group artist by new { genre.GenreId, artist.ArtistName };

// Count up the number of artists in each genre
var genres_by_artist =
    from pair in genres_and_artist
    group pair by pair.Key;
```

> Actual:
>
> - Key { GenreId = 1, ArtistName = "4 Non Blondes" }
> - Group Count = 1
> - Key { GenreId = 1, ArtistName = "Adam and The Ants" }
> - Group Count = 1
>
> Expected:
>
> - Key { GenreId = 1, { ArtistName = "4 Non Blondes", ArtistName = "Adam and The Ants" }  }
> - Group Count = 2

Comment: It works like you think it should. Check your data :)

Comment: Each Group is a unique pair GenreId and ArtistName.  You do not have any rows of data with duplicates using both keys.  Try grouping by only one key and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're after a listing of artists per genre. When you group the artist names by `GenreId` you're already nearly there:

```cs
var genres_and_artist =
    from artist in db.Artists
    join track in db.Tracks on artist.ArtistId equals track.ArtistId
    join genre in db.Genres on track.GenreId equals genre.GenreId
    group artist.ArtistName by genre.GenreId;
```

This produces groups in which the artists are multiplied by as many songs as they have in the genre (in fact, it's songs grouped by `GenreId`, but only showing songs' artist names), so what's left is making the names distinct, either by...

```cs
var artists_by_genre =
    from grouping in genres_and_artist
    select new
    {
        GenreId = grouping.Key,
        Artists = grouping.Distinct()
    };
```

...or...

```cs
var artists_by_genre =
    from grouping in genres_and_artist
    select new
    {
        GenreId = grouping.Key,
        Artists = grouping.GroupBy(name => name).Select(g => g.Key)
    };
```

Comment: Gert Arnold - perfect, thanks!

Comment: @JohnScott: the correct way to say "Thanks" is to upvote and/or accept the answer

Comment: I did - but it doesn't register as I don't have enough 'reputation'